# Disable ViewPager2 item animator

Tags: android, animation, android-viewpager2

I'm using ViewPager2 with ListAdapter. Every time dataset get changes, item of viewpager2 displays an animation. Is there any way to disable it? In recyclerview we can disable by setting `recyclerview.itemAnimator = null` but what about viewpager2?

Answer (score 0):

Found a workaround to this problem: setting an empty *PageTransformer*

```
pager.setPageTransformer { p0, p1 -> }
```

By looking at the ViewPager2 implementation this unfortunately seems to be the only way to set the internal RecyclerView's animator to null.

```
public void setPageTransformer(@Nullable ViewPager2.PageTransformer transformer) {
        if (transformer != null) {
            if (!this.mSavedItemAnimatorPresent) {
                this.mSavedItemAnimator = this.mRecyclerView.getItemAnimator();
                this.mSavedItemAnimatorPresent = true;
            }

            this.mRecyclerView.setItemAnimator((ItemAnimator)null);
        } else if (this.mSavedItemAnimatorPresent) {
            this.mRecyclerView.setItemAnimator(this.mSavedItemAnimator);
            this.mSavedItemAnimator = null;
            this.mSavedItemAnimatorPresent = false;
        }

        if (transformer != this.mPageTransformerAdapter.getPageTransformer()) {
            this.mPageTransformerAdapter.setPageTransformer(transformer);
            this.requestTransform();
        }
    }
```